# Don't restore form values on tab restore in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can able to reset all form field values in java script, but when i closed tab and restoring the tab again i can see the form field values, I don't want to show it after restoring the tabs, but the same page i can't see form field values after restoring the page in Firefox, this is what i expected but why chrome is not working? This is browser behavior or else can we do any script to clear the values for restoring the tabs.

Comment: *"I can able to reset all form field values in java script, but when i closed tab and restoring the tab again i can see the form field values"* Can you be a bit clearer about **exactly** what you're doing?

Comment: sure, for instance, i have a form along with multiple fields and also when the user click the submit button values will be stored in session storage. Now what i'm expecting while user closing the browser tab without clicking the submit button. i don't want to show the form field values which user entered, while user restoring (ctrl+shift+T) the closed browser tab

Comment: So the user fills in some fields, closes the browser tab, and reopens the browser tab, and you want the fields *not* to be filled in?

Comment: yes, if the user didn't submit the form, then i don't want to show it.

Comment: All due respect, as a user, I would be cross. If I go to the trouble of filling in the fields, **accidentally** close the tab, and reopen it, I'd be cross if the values weren't there (and would probably consider it a bug in Chrome). Strongly recommend just leaving it, reopening a tab is like "undo".

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force clear all input fields in your page, with jQuery:

```
$('input, textarea').val('');
```

Just place it into your page, it will be executed on page load.